# Strange Jetpack Compose Navigation Transition Behavior

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm wondering why I get this weird transition when navigating to my Settings screen too quickly (video on YouTube: https://youtube.com/shorts/UPv66zqHMbo?feature=share).
Here's all the related code (this is a multi-module app):

Code for my navigation graph:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.settingsGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = SettingsGraphDestination.InitialScreen.route,
        route = SETTINGS_GRAPH_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(
            route= SettingsGraphDestination.InitialScreen.route,
            enterTransition = {
                fadeIn(tween(durationMillis = CommonConstants.NAVIGATION_ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS))
            },
            exitTransition =  {
                fadeOut(tween(durationMillis = CommonConstants.NAVIGATION_ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS))
            }
        ) {
            SettingsScreen(
                navController = navController,
                onPhoneNumberSettingScreenClicked = {
                    navController.navigate(
                        SettingsGraphDestination.PhoneNumberAdjustment.route
                    )
                },
                onStepStrideAdjustmentScreenClicked = {
                    navController.navigate(
                        SettingsGraphDestination.StepStrideAdjustment.route
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
    }
```

SettingsScreen.kt:

```
    NirvanaScaffold(
        navController = navController,
        screenTitle = "تنظیمات"
    ) {
         Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(nirvanaScreenBackgroundBrush)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f))

            ButtonsArea(
                onSubscriptionButtonClicked = { onSubscriptionScreenClicked() },
                onChangePhoneNumberButtonClicked = { onPhoneNumberSettingScreenClicked() },
                onChangeStepStrideButtonClicked = { onStepStrideAdjustmentScreenClicked() },
                onChangeWeightButtonClicked = { onWeightAdjustmentScreenClicked() }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        }
    }
}
```

RootGraph.kt:

```
dashboardGraph(
            navController = navController,
            nestedGraphs = {
                settingsGraph(navController = navController)
            },
            navigateToSettingsGraph = {navController.navigateToSettingsGraph()}
        )
    }
```

Does anybody know what may be causing this problem? I've tried deleting the enterTransition and exitTransition arguments also, but it did not work!

Comment: what's strange, that the activity comes down from the top left?

Comment: @Blundell yes, rather than fading in only.

Comment: try a different phone/emulator it could be a system animation or the Launcher that you are using.

Comment: @Blundell but I get this behavior on my Android phone, so I have to solve the issue to make sure it will run correctly on all types of Android devices.

Comment: I meant try another device to prove if the problem is indeed your code or external to you. Once you've determined that you know if you are debugging a problem or attempting to override default behaviour

Comment: I have the same issue with animation, I use the default one. It works well with navigation version `2.7.0`, but if I use any version above I have the top left animation.

Comment: It can be related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295536728

Comment: @ch13mob downgrading to 2.7.0 looks like a good workaround for now since the problem is still there even in 2.7.5. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 7):

I have found another solution that works with navigation 2.7.6 in my case, I just added `.fillMaxSize()` modifier in my `NavHost`:

```
...    
TemplateTheme {
                Surface(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Scaffold(
                        snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
                        content = { paddingValues ->
                            NavHost(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                                    .padding(paddingValues),
                                navController = navController,
...
```

I'm also using a single top-level `Scaffold` in the app

Comment: will give this a shot and come back asap (still relying on the older version)!